# mongodb mapreduce groupby twice

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb and try to count how many distinct login users per day from existing collection. The data in collection looks like following

```
[{
    _id: xxxxxx,
    properties: {
        uuid: '4b5b5c2e208811e3b5a722000a97015e',
        time: ISODate("2014-12-13T00:00:00Z"),
        type: 'login'
    }
}]
```

Due to my limited knowledge, what I figure out so far is group by day first, output the data to a tmp collection and use this tmp collection to do anther map reduce and output the result to a final collection. This solution will get my collections bigger which I do not really like it. Does anyone can help me out or any good/more complex tutorials that I can follow? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a map reduce, I would suggest an [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/). You can think of an aggregation as somewhat like a linux pipe, in that you can pass the results of one operation to the next. With this strategy, you can perform 2 consecutive groups and never have to write anything to the database.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148955/mongo-distinct-aggegation/25149052#25149052) for more details on the specifics.

Comment: yes, Aggregation pipe line will solve the problem. however, my case is a bit tricky which I did not mention in my post. I need to handle timezone in my mapreduce functions as well, therefore I think I have to use mapreduce instead of aggregation pipeline

Comment: Yeah, that makes it a bit more difficult. Depending on how you're storing timezone, you might be able to do some fancy stuff with the `$project` operator to convert time zones. See the second answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287493/how-to-deal-with-the-timezone-issue-when-storing-dates-in-utc-using-mongod for more details.