# Find data without repetitions multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb

Good morning, I am learning MongoDB but when trying to make a query I do not achieve the desired results.

The structure of the documents used is as follows:

```
use empresa

db.departamento_dos.insert (
{
 "Codigo": 2,
 "Nombre": "Contabilidad",
 "Presupuesto": 10000,
 "Empleados": 
 {
  "Empleado": { "DNI": "10340", "Nombre": "Andres", "Apellido": "Lopez"},
  "Empleado": { "DNI": "10341", "Nombre": "Paula", "Apellido": "Tovar"},
  "Empleado": { "DNI": "10342", "Nombre": "Andres", "Apellido": "Perez"},
  "Empleado": { "DNI": "10343", "Nombre": "Camila", "Apellido": "Perez"},
  "Empleado": { "DNI": "10344", "Nombre": "Cristian", "Apellido": "Forero"}
 }
}
)
```

and

```
db.departamento_tres.insert (
{
 "Codigo": 77,
 "Nombre": "Marketing",
 "Presupuesto": 30000,
 "Empleados": 
 {
  "Empleado uno": { "DNI": "10350", "Nombre": "Maria", "Apellido": "Perez"},
  "Empleado dos": { "DNI": "10351", "Nombre": "Angie", "Apellido": "Gómez"},
  "Empleado tres": { "DNI": "10352", "Nombre": "Andrea", "Apellido": "Lopez"},
  "Empleado cuatro": { "DNI": "10353", "Nombre": "Cristina", "Apellido": "Riaño"},
  "Empleado cinco": { "DNI": "10354", "Nombre": "Annie", "Apellido": "Castellanos"}
 }
}
)
```

My question is: how can I make a query by "Apellido" by eliminating repeated "Apellidos"?

I tried to use the different operator with a regular expression to auto-complete the query, but not work.

```
db.departamento_uno.distinct( "Empleados.Empleado", { /.*".Apellido"} )
```

and it always shows me an empty vector.

The idea is to be able to consult the two documents simultaneously. For example, the result I'm looking for would be:

```
[ "Lopez", "Tovar", "Perez", "Forero", "Gómez", "Riaño", "Castellanos"]
```

since the idea is to show each surname only once no matter how many times it appears

Any idea how you can make this query?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo Distinct Aggegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148955/mongo-distinct-aggegation)

Comment: Why is your documents have different schema ( Empleado vs  Empleado uno )? Is it by design ? It would be easier to query if you can follow same schema for all documents.

Comment: @Veeram Yes, it is by design since the idea is to be able to modify a scheme without affecting the rest. Although as I am new, I do not know if it is the most optimal or convenient.

Comment: Can you change `Empleados` to array ? Something like `"Empleados": 
 [
  { "DNI": "10350", "Nombre": "Maria", "Apellido": "Perez"},
 { "DNI": "10351", "Nombre": "Angie", "Apellido": "Gómez"},

...
]`. This makes it easy to query and you can get distinct values using `db.departamento_uno.distinct( "Empleados.Empleado.Apellido")`

Comment: @Veeram Yes, I could change it, as long as it respects that they belong to a different department. But if I unify all my arrangement of employees as I would identify those belonging to the same department?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `db.departamento_uno.distinct( "Empleados.Apellido")` earlier. Yes, so would have something like `[{
 "Codigo": 77,
 "Nombre": "Marketing"....
 "Empleados": [ { "DNI": "10350", "Nombre": "Maria", "Apellido": "Perez"}, { "DNI": "10351", "Nombre": "Angie", "Apellido": "Gómez"}, ... ]},{
 "Codigo": 2...
}]`

Comment: @Veeram Thank you, that form works for the moment, but was there a way to execute the query in the schemas at the same time to only show the "Apellido" once?

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Can you give me an example ? Please also refer to documentation for learning.

Comment: @Veeram For example, in department two and three the surname "perez" appears 3 times; if I execute the query separately in each of the documents it will be sent once, it is possible to filter two schemes at the same time to avoid this. I have been reading the documentation and I do not find anything about this topic. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Np. I'm still not clear. What query do you execute ? distinct query ? `db.departamento_uno.distinct( "Empleados.Apellido")` doesn't return what you need ? It gets the distinct values across entire collection.

Comment: @Veeram When I execute the query `db.departamento_uno.distinct( "Empleados.Apellido")` and the query `db.departamento_dos.distinct( "Empleados.Apellido")` the query gives me the "Apellidos" separately. My question is Is there a way to join these separate queries into one so that only the data appears once? My question is Is there a way to join these separate queries into one so that only the data appears once?
Example: Apellido: Perez appears in both schemes; what I'm looking for is that as it appears in the first schema, it does not appear again when I execute the query in the second schema.

Comment: I thought you just had one collection all this time. Accept my sincere apologies. Do you have any join criteria for two collection ? If no separate queries is the only way.

Comment: @Veeram My join criteria is the "DNI" of each employee. Reading the documentation I found the operator $lookup but I don't understand how I could apply it in my query to make a join between the two collections.

Comment: So $lookup is not applicable here. That doesn't look like a join criteria. You have different values in each collection. It looks to me it just two separate collection storing the similar document you should just do two distinct queries and perform another distinct on the client side against two collection results.

Comment: @Veeram I think it would be the most optimal solution, so I will. Thanks for the help.
But in the case that in the "DNI": were the same values ​​in some cases, could I apply $lookup to effect the union?

Comment: Np. Yes you can.